# Agrupar Array() PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte array()

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [usu_id] => 1
            [mod_base] => 1
            [mod_id] => 4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [usu_id] => 1
            [mod_base] => 1
            [mod_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [usu_id] => 1
            [mod_base] => 1
            [mod_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Preciso agrupar pelo campo mod_base.
Como faço?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/020233e12163ed214345261b1738be6c0a3bea09

Comment: Você precisa agrupar pelo mod_base, mas, qual layout que deseja que fique, como seria o resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer por exemplo um *foreach* em que armazena os valores no *mod_base* num novo array e depois imprime-o

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'mod_base'){
        array_push($new_array, $value);
    }
}
```

Acho que não me enganei e isso funcionará e resolve seu problema.